# Название сайта в title

Tags: html

Нужно изменить заголовок статьи **/** страницы, который высвечивается в Google поиске. Поставил аббревиатуру сайта в начало заголовка каждой статьи **/** страницы, но никак не получается убрать название сайта, смотрите на фото [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html b:version='2' class='v2' expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'> 
  <head> 
    <meta content='YJd8rH_OtQT6bAcnGgVZ5Vo2aPS7KnoN1O0NgMrq95g' name='google-site-verification'/>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport'/>

    <b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
    <title>
      <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
        <data:blog.pageTitle/> | Unusual Spots, Attractions, Resorts And Much More Right Here!
        <b:else/>
        <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType != &quot;error_page&quot;'>
          <data:blog.title/> | <data:blog.pageName/>
          <b:else/>
          ERROR 404 | <data:blog.title/> 
        </b:if>
      </b:if>
    </title>

    <!-- Description and Keywords (start) -->
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;index&quot;'>
      <meta content='YOUR DESCRIPTION HERE' name='description'/>
    </b:if>
    <meta content='YOUR KEYWORDS HERE' name='keywords'/>
    <!-- Description and Keywords (end) -->
    <b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == &quot;item&quot;'>
      <meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' property='og:title'/>
      <meta expr:content='data:blog.canonicalUrl' property='og:url'/>
      <meta content='article' property='og:type'/>
    </b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.postImageUrl'>
      <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' property='og:image'/>
      <b:else/>
      <b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
        <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' property='og:image'/>
      </b:if></b:if>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription != &quot;&quot;'>
      <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='og:description'/>
    </b:if>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.title' property='og:site_name'/>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.homepageUrl' name='twitter:domain'/>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' name='twitter:title'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.postImageUrl'>
      <meta content='summary_large_image' name='twitter:card'/>
      <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageUrl' name='twitter:image'/>
      <b:else/>
      <meta content='summary' name='twitter:card'/>
      <b:if cond='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl'>
        <meta expr:content='data:blog.postImageThumbnailUrl' name='twitter:image'/> 
      </b:if>
    </b:if>
    <meta expr:content='data:blog.pageName' name='twitter:title'/>
    <b:if cond='data:blog.metaDescription'>
      <meta expr:content='data:blog.metaDescription' name='twitter:description'/>
    </b:if>
    <!-- Social Media meta tag need customer customization -->
    <meta content='Facebook App ID here' property='fb:app_id'/> 
    <meta content='Facebook Admin ID here' property='fb:admins'/> 
    <meta content='@username' name='twitter:site'/>
    <meta content='@username' name='twitter:creator'/> 

    <link href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,600,500|Lato:400,700,900|Open+Sans:400,700,600' rel='stylesheet'/>
    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js'/>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
      //<![CDATA[
      $(document).ready(main);
      var cond = 1;
      function main() {
        var _0xf636=["\x76\x61\x6C","\x2E\x63\x72\x65\x64\x69\x74","\x68\x72\x65\x66","\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E","\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x74\x65\x6D\x70\x6C\x61\x74\x65\x62\x69\x74\x73\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D","\x61\x74\x74\x72"];var _0x333f=[_0xf636[0],_0xf636[1],_0xf636[2],_0xf636[3],_0xf636[4],_0xf636[5]];var aa=$(_0x333f[1])[_0x333f[0]]();if(aa== null){window[_0x333f[3]][_0x333f[2]]= _0x333f[4]};$(_0x333f[1])[_0x333f[5]](_0x333f[2],_0x333f[4])
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.visibility = "visible";

        if($('.entry-content').text().length < 500){ $('.entry-content').css('padding-bottom', '20px'); $('.post-footer .social').hide(); };

        var imgclass = $('.post-body').find('img:first');
        $(imgclass).addClass('remove');

        $("a").has("img").addClass("imglink");

        if( $('li:has(ul)') ) {
          $("li:has(ul)").find("a:first").append('<i class="fa fa-caret-down caret" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
        }

        $('.comments').each(function() {
          if($('.comments-content', this).length > 0) {
            $("#comments").css('display','block');
          } else { $("#comments").css('display','none'); }
        });

        $('ul').find('li:has(ul)').children('a').removeAttr('href');

        $('li:has(ul)').click(function() {
          $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
        });

        $('.bt-menu').click(function() {
          $('header nav').slideToggle();
        });

        $('.search-icon').click(function() {
          $('.search-box').slideToggle(100);
        });

        var menu = jQuery('header nav');    
        jQuery(window).on('resize', function() {     
          if(!jQuery(".menu-bar").is(":visible") && !menu.is(':visible'))
          {
            menu.css({'display':''});   
          }
        });  
      }

      function createThumb(pID){
        var div = document.getElementById(pID);
        var imgtag = "";
        var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
        if(img.length>=1) {

          var url = img[0].src;
          url = url.replace('/s320','');
          url = url.replace('/s1600','');
          url = url.replace('/s640','');
          url = url.replace('/s400','');
          url = url.replace('/s200','');
          imgtag = '<div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('+url+');"></div>';


        }
        div.innerHTML = imgtag;
      }

      function createThumbl(pID, pURL, pTITLE){
        var div = document.getElementById(pID);
        var imgtag = "";
        var img = div.getElementsByTagName("img");
        if(img.length>=1) {

          var url = img[0].src;
          url = url.replace('/s320','');
          url = url.replace('/s1600','');
          url = url.replace('/s640','');
          url = url.replace('/s400','');
          url = url.replace('/s200','');
          imgtag = '<a href="'+ pURL +'" title="'+ pTITLE+'"><div class="thumb" style="background-image: url('+url+');"></div></a>';


        }
        div.innerHTML = imgtag;

      }
      //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: читал официальные рекомендации поисковых систем? https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35624?hl=ru https://yandex.ru/support/webmaster/search-results/site-description.xml

Comment: Практически каждый сайт имеет название в заголовке в выдаче, а я просто хочу переставить его с конца на перед, вот и все, но в блогере почему-то высвечиваются два названия причем второе, которое в конце, я нигде не могу найти чтобы изменить ни в шаблоне, ни в настройках... Написал в службу поддержи, пока тихо.

Comment: `я нигде не могу найти чтобы изменить ни в шаблоне` поисковик составил снипет из имени домена. Поэтому я привёл ссылки для ознакомления с правилами , по которым поисковики составляют снипеты. Вы их читали?